# Is there a way to render an action's js template from a js.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have tried  `<%= render :template =>'resources/new', :format => "js" %>`, but nothing happens.

Edit: Also I don't know how to send parameters to a .js template.

Comment: Did you try `render 'resources/new.js` ?

Comment: Worked with `render :template => 'resourcers/new.js'`, but I don't know how to pass parameters to the template. Have to google a bit.

Comment: I found out what to do: `render :template => 'resources/new.js', :locals => {:link_id => "register_similar"}`

Comment: Good digging! You should post your results as an answer and accept it when you can (2 days I think), so that this question will be marked as "answered" and more people will benefit from it. Kudos.

Comment: FWIW, this is in the docs, see [rendering action's view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-view) and [passing local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
render :template => 'resources/new.js', :locals => {:link_id => "register_similar"}
```

In the recieving js.erb file:

```
var link_id = '<%= link_id %>'
```